# ElasticSearch - index and store attributes of string field in explicit mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm writting this post because i am new ES user and i am not sure if i understand correctly index and store attributes of string fields in explict mapping.

I want to have an ES index which contans list of internet sites.
The document type "site" has 3 fields: url, content, inner_note

I will be searching documents which contains given phrases in "content" field.
I will be retrieving single document which has particular url in "url" field.
The field "inner_note" is only for my internal use and i will not use  this field to searching/retrieving documents.

I prepared following mapping:

```
"site" : {
    "properties" : {
        "url" : {"type" : "string","store" : "no", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
        "content" : {"type" : "string", "store" : "yes", "index" : "analyzed"},
        "inner_note" : {"type" : "string","store" : "no", "index" : "no"}
    }
```

and i have following questions:

1. Have i choosed optimal "store" and "index" attributes for my scenario?
2. Is retrieving document by url field as fast as i would retrieve by ID?  Comparing to traditional SQL version: if i want to retrieve single row in SQL table by WHERE url = ? i would create SQL index on url column.

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: what is site is it index name or type name or what ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping that you posted looks good for your usecase.

You want to search on both url and content, thus they are indexed (default). Url is not analyzed while content is, so that you can run full-text queries on it.

The third field is neither indexed nor stored, but you can still get it back as part of the `_source` field, which contains the whole document that you submitted.

Retrieving a document by id is the same as retrieving it by url in your case, since the field is not analyzed. IN fact id is internally a non analyzed field in the lucene document, exactly like the url field.

Comment: Thank you very much for clear answer. I have one more question: do i have to set store = yes for "content" field if i want to run fun-text queries on it? I thought i have to, but yesterday i read few topics on stackoverflow and i am not sure right now :)

Comment: No you just need to index it, which is enabled by default. To keep it short you only need `store:yes` if you disable the `_source` field and you want to retrieve a field in the search results.

Comment: Have a read of [this answer on what the store and index parameters do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911633/not-indexed-field-is-stored-in-index/16923084#16923084) if you want to know more...