# How to not-analyze in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, token, analyzer, verbatim

I've got a field in an ElasticSearch field which I do not want to have analyzed, i. e. it should be stored and compared verbatim.  The values will contain letters, numbers, whitespace, dashes, slashes and maybe other characters.

If I do not give an analyzer in my mapping for this field, the default still uses a tokenizer which hacks my verbatim string into chunks of words.  I don't want that.

Is there a super simple analyzer which, basically, does not analyze?  Or is there a different way of denoting that this field shall not be analyzed?

I only create the index, I don't do anything else.  I can use analyzers like "english" for other fields which seems to be built-in names for pre-configured analyzers.  Is there a list of other names?  Maybe there's one fitting my needs (namely doing nothing with the input).

This is my mapping currently:

```
{
  "my_type": {
    "properties": {
      "my_field1": { "type": "string", "analyzer": "english" },
      "my_field2": { "type": "string" }
    }
  }
}
```

`my_field1` is language-dependent; this seems to work.  `my_field2` shall be verbatim.  I'd like to give an analyzer there which simply does not do anything.

A sample value for `my_field2` would be `"B45c 14/04"`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
"my_field2": {
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

Check you here, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-core-types.html, for further info.

Comment: Ah!  That's what I was looking for.  I stumbled across that `not_analyzed` several times, but always thought using it would mean that it cannot be searched at all (apparently that's what `no` is used for).  The link to the documentation was enlightening, thank you!  (And given time I will accept this answer unless sth even more helpful appears.)

Comment: @Alfe, you can have at [this answer for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911633/not-indexed-field-is-stored-in-index/16923084#16923084) including the option `index: no`

Comment: Can we set it globally so, it doesn't analyze string type for all?

Comment: By default if we dont add 'index': 'not_analyzed' what gonna happen then? does there a default analyzer?

Answer (score 54):

This is no longer true due to the removal of the `string` (replaced by `keyword` and `text`) type as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings). Instead you should use `keyword` type with `"index": true | false`.

For Example OLD:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "type" "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
}
```

becomes NEW:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "type" "keyword",
    "index": true
  }
}
```

This means the field is indexed but as it is typed as `keyword` not analyzed implicitly. If you would like to have the field analyzed, you need to use `text` type.

Comment: It seems it's "enabled": true/false instead of "index" https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/enabled.html

Comment: @theseadroid No, `"enabled":false`  will prevent receiving the field at all (except manual parsing of _source field), while `"index":false` will prevent only searching/aggregations.

Comment: Besides, `enabled` is only for `object` fields or the entire document mapping. Not for `keyword` fields.

Answer (score 3):

`keyword` analyser can be also used.

```
// don't actually use this, use "index": "not_analyzed" instead
{
  "my_type": {
    "properties": {
      "my_field1": { "type": "string", "analyzer": "english" },
      "my_field2": { "type": "string", "analyzer": "keyword" }
    }
  }
}
```

As noted here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html, it makes more sense to mark those fields as `not_analyzed`.

But `keyword` analyzer can be useful when it is set by default for whole index.

UPDATE: As it said in comments, `string` is no longer supported in 5.X

Comment: actually, the `keyword` analyzer does analyze the field, but only just once as a whole. it might be not desired when this is setted up on some large text fields like ~MB contents - it will go into the index and eat some resources.

Comment: Moreover, the `string` field is unsupported for indexes created in 5.x in favor of the `text` and `keyword` fields.

Answer (score 1):

for API 8.5 the old answers wont work, and I found the solution by accident, just set property to "enabled=false", check the official doc, there is example inside https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html