# What is a multi-token string?

Tags: string, elasticsearch, mapping, token, kibana

Was browsing Elasticsearch issues on github and came across [this comment](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/1191#issuecomment-42052361) stating that:

> Multi-token string fields are not sortable by Elasticsearch in any
>   predictable way.

For reference we are talking here about a string timestamp in the form "14/05/08-13:41:23".

From the context, I would assume that any non alphanumerical string (with other chars than [A-Za-z0-9]) would be a multi-token String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I misinterpreted it for a general concept about strings that I would not known, but it seems to actually be Elasticsearch specific Jargon:

By default, when processing fields mapped as strings, ElasticSearch parses them and tries to broke them into multiple tokens, and it seems to be the case for strings containing `/` or . As a consequence, those strings become "multi token strings". To avoid that, one need to edit the mappings of ElasticSearch and set the field as "not_analyzed", eg:

```
"my_field2": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235996/how-to-not-analyze-in-elasticsearch) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309626/aggregating-a-list-of-http-log-paths-in-kibana/24330429#24330429) for reference.