# Elasticsearch Java API search with regex

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch

I would like to get some data from my Elasticsearch server locally, with help of "regexpQuery", and for this I made the following method :

```
public void getProductsStartingWithString() throws ParseException {

    Client client = getClient();

    SearchResponse response = null;

    BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("ProductCode", "FA.*"));

    if (response == null || response.getHits().hits().length != 0) {

        response = client.prepareSearch("warehouse-550")
                .setTypes("core2")
                .setQuery(boolQuery)
                .setSize(100)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
    }

    response.getHits();

}
```

The documents in Elasticsearch looks like this :

```
{
  "_index": "warehouse-550",
  "_type": "core2",
  "_id": "AVOKD0Pq8h4KkDGZwBom",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "3,550,162.06,FALK0011927540Y,2016-03-16;08:00:00.000\r",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-03-16T07:00:00.000Z",
    "path": "D:/Programs/Logstash/x_testingLocally/processed-stocklevels-550-42190516032016.csv",
    "host": "EVO385",
    "type": "core2",
    "Quantity": 3,
    "Warehouse": "550",
    "Price": 162.06,
    "ProductCode": "FALK0011927540Y",
    "Timestamp": "2016-03-16;08:00:00.000"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1458111600000
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1458111600000
  ]
}
```

But on response, I get always 0 hits.

The output of : `curl -XGET "172.22.130.189:9200/warehouse-550/_mapping/core2?pretty"`:

```
{
  "warehouse-550" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "core2" : {
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "@version" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "Price" : {
            "type" : "double"
          },
          "ProductCode" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "Quantity" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "Timestamp" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "Warehouse" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "host" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "message" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "path" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "type" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I do wrong ?

Comment: Is there any analyzer specified on ProductCode. regexp applies to the terms produced by the tokenizer for that field, and not to the original text of the field.

Comment: @rahulroc, I'm a beginner in using Elasticsearch and Java API for it. I don't understand your statement/question.

Comment: Then you need to read https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html. Also, please provide the output of curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/warehouse-550/_mapping/core2'

Comment: @rahulroc, I have added the output for that command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default analyzer for ProductCode is [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/standard-analyzer.html)

If we were to reimplement the standard analyzer as a custom analyzer, it would be defined as follows:

```
{
    "type":      "custom",
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "filter":  [ "lowercase", "stop" ]
}
```

If you notice the `"lowercase"` filter, it converts the text to lowercase.

> FALK0011927540Y gets converted to falk0011927540y

Hence, when you are searching for `"FA.*"`, there is no match.

Solution :

- Search by lowercasing on your client side. For eg. `"fa.*"`
- map your ProductCode as [not_analyzed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235996/how-to-not-analyze-in-elasticsearch). It will store it as it is.