# How to perform AND condition in elasticsearch query?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have the following query where I want to query the indexname for ID "abc_12-def that fall within the date range specified in the range filter.

But the below query is fetching values of different ID as well(for eg: abc_12-edf, abc_12-pgf etc) and that fall outside the date range. Any advice on how I can give an AND condition here? Thanks.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/indexname/status/_search?pretty=1&size=1000000' -d '{
"query": {
"filtered" : {
  "filter": [ 
    { "term":  { "ID": "abc_12-def" }}, 
    { "range": { "Date": { "gte": "2015-10-01T09:12:11", "lte" : "2015-11-18T10:10:13" }}} 
  ]
  }
  }
  }'
```

Comment: It seems your `id` field `analyzed`??

Comment: Can you please explain what that means?

Comment: Check the mappings using `GET /index_name/type_name/_mapping` and specify in question.

Comment: It's not analyzed I think.

Comment: Please share the mapping in question. By default all string fields are `analyzed`

Comment: This is the mapping for that particular field: ID":{"type":"string"}

Comment: If no analyzer is mentioned, strings are `analyzed` by default. So, your ID field is `analyzed`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) for `AND` aka `MUST` condition

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "ID": "abc_12-def"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "Date": {
              "gte": "2015-10-01T09:12:11",
              "lte": "2015-11-18T10:10:13"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Also, all fields by default are analyzed using [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), which means *abc_12-def* is tokenized as [abc_12, def]. `term query` does not analyze the string.

If you are looking for an exact match, you should mark the field as `not_analyzed`. How to map it as [not_analyzed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235996/how-to-not-analyze-in-elasticsearch) is explained here.