# QueryContainerDescriptor Elasticsearch - Get all document with description is not equal to String.Empty

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, asp.net-core-2.2

im using QueryContainerDescriptor to fill a filter.
i want to get all the document that their description is not equal to String.Empty.

i tried to do :

```
        public static QueryContainerDescriptor<T> FilterSummaryEmpty<T>(this QueryContainerDescriptor<T> qd)
where T : ElasticEntityDoc
        {           
            qd.Bool(b=> 
                        b.MustNot(mn =>                        
                            mn.Term(f => f.Description, string.Empty)
                        ));

            return qd;
        }
```

but its not working.

Also i tried to use regex for it but without success.
what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the analyser used for `description` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `standard analyser`, checking empty will not work because it will not be analysed as it is empty. So there won't be nothing as `empty` in the index to match for.

To check this, you need to make copy of the field in another field as `not_analyzed` in your mapping. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235996/how-to-not-analyze-in-elasticsearch)
So you can check empty on copied field and other queries on `description` field.

There is one more way of checking that. You can use [exists](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html)

> While a field is deemed non-existent if the JSON value is null or [], these values will indicate the field does exist:
>
> Empty strings, such as "" or "-" Arrays containing null and another
> value, such as [null, "foo"] A custom null-value, defined in field
> mapping