# Can you index fields in elasticsearch that cant be searched?

Tags: elasticsearch

Are you able to index text fields that cannot be searched on when the user trys to perform any kind of search/match query?

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by index? If you mean that the data will be returned to you, but has no effect on searching then use `index: no` in your mapping. You can read more about it [from this answer on the different `index: ?` settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911633/not-indexed-field-is-stored-in-index/16923084#16923084)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, just exclude them from `_all` if you do general purpose query by setting `include_in_all` to false: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types/

As all query run on the `_all` field by default; this should do the trick.